# Find next instance of class (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to find the next element of a given class, from the third element of another class, in order to write after the first of them. I have tried this:

```
$(".class1").eq(2).next().find('.class2').after('<div...');
```

the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div id="data1977654">
        <button id="1977654" type="button" class="class1">Send</button>
    </div>                            
</div>

<div id="panel-1977654" class="row">
    <div class="class2"></div>
</div>
```

But this not works.

Comment: Assuming the elements are siblings you don't need `find()`, however we really need to see the associated HTML in order to help you accurately.

Comment: kindly show us your html and explain where you want what

Comment: Ok, I have put the HTML code.

Comment: i think html is missing because i can not able to see another class1

Comment: It repeats the same always. That would be the content of the third element of class1 that is what I want to find

Answer (score 0):

You can find the siblings using `nextAll` and then use `:first` to get the first occurrence.

```
$(".class1").eq(2).nextAll('.contentDiv:first')
```